# Upload a file to Google Storage on GAE Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Which is the best way to upload a file generated by my Google App Engine app to Google Storage? My GAE app is in java.

I tried to use JetS3t but it didn't work on GAE because it use threads.

Answer (score 1):

[Google APIs Java Client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) is a recommended way to access Google APIs from [Java clients](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/JavaEnvironments). There are examples for most APIs, but unfortunately not yet for Storage (the issue mentioned was resolved).

Comment: Ok, I'll try to implement this using the java clients. Thanks.

Comment: **From GoogleAPI's:** _NOTE: this API is currently not supported due to [Issue 68](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/issues/detail?id=68). It will be fixed in the 1.2.2-alpha version release of google-api-java-client._

Comment: Version is already 1.4.1 and the issue 68 was fixed six months ago.